# How can my widget build() method update the Text in a Row

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm new to flutter.  I think I understand some of the ideas - specifically the build() method is how you make changes, by recreating things, not by changing things.

But I'm confused by this.  In my `build()` I try to create a new Row(), with a new Text() as one of its children.  But `dart` is complaining that "the values in a const list literal must be const."

Note, this is a stripped down version of what I actually wrote.  I understand that I need to be calling setState() to make things change. But I don't really understand why `displayText` is not a `const Text`.  Or, exactly why it has to be a `const Text` since the `Text` itself is immutable, and I am building a whole new `Row`.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class GameTimer extends StatefulWidget {
  final TextStyle timerStyle;
  const GameTimer({Key? key, required this.timerStyle}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  State createState() => _TimerState();
}

class _TimerState extends State<GameTimer> {
  final startedAt = DateTime.now();
  String timerDisplay() {
    int minutes = (DateTime.now().difference(startedAt).inSeconds / 60).floor();
    return '$minutes';
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var displayText = Text(timerDisplay(), style: widget.timerStyle); // this is not const Text
    return Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
        children: const <Widget>[
          Icon(Icons.play_circle),
          displayText, // <== "the values in a const list literal must be const."
        ]);
  }
}
```

How can a Widget build() method change the Text in the Row() based on the state?  This is flutter 3.5, dart 2.14.

Comment: Just remove const  (children: const <Widget>[) because const value never changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`const` widgets cannot be updated using a variable.

```dart
Text("Some text");
```

This is a `const` Text widget.

```dart
Text(textValueVariable);
```

This is not a `const` Widget. Because the value of `textValueVariable` can be changed.

Using `const` avoids unnecessary rebuilds of the widget.

In your scenario,

```dart
class GameTimer extends StatefulWidget {
  const GameTimer({
    Key? key,
    required this.timerStyle,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final TextStyle timerStyle;

  @override
  State createState() => _TimerState();
}

class _TimerState extends State<GameTimer> {
  final startedAt = DateTime.now();

  // Initial value of Text
  String _timerDisplay = '0';

  void updateTimerDisplay() {
    int minutes = (DateTime.now().difference(startedAt).inSeconds / 60).floor();

    // Update value of Text
    setState(() {
      _timerDisplay = minutes.toString();
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
      children: [
        const Icon(Icons.play_circle), // Only this Icon widget is a const
        Text(
          _timerDisplay,
          style: widget.timerStyle,
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, the changes you made are useful to understand how the code needs to be structured.

Comment: @Marvin, If this answer helped to solve your question, consider marking it accepted.

Comment: I was giving some time to see any other answers appeared.  But, a week is enough.  Thanks!